# Haskell Understanding Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

Just trying to get my head round monads...

looking at this page at the moment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Simple_monad_examples

at the bottom it asks what do these snippets resolve to:

```
Just 0 >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )
```

Why does this return Nothing? Because of the fail call?

```
Nothing >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )
```

I understand this one.

Comment: Thanks all for confirming and explanation :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As always in Haskell, you can usually understand some code by inlining and term rewriting:

We have:

```
Prelude> Just 0 >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )
Nothing
```

The most important thing we need is the definition of `fail` and `>>=` for the `Maybe` monad, given as:

```
instance  Monad Maybe  where
    (Just x) >>= k      = k x
    Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing

    (Just _) >>  k      = k
    Nothing  >>  _      = Nothing

    return              = Just
    fail _              = Nothing
```

so we have:

```
Just 0 >>= (\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) )

-- by definition of >>=
(\ x -> if (x == 0) then fail "zero" else Just (x + 1) ) 0

-- by definition of fail
(\ x -> if (x == 0) then Nothing else Just (x + 1) ) 0

-- beta reduce
if 0 == 0 then Nothing else Just (0 + 1)

-- Integer math
if True then Nothing else Just 1

-- evaluate `if`
Nothing
```

and there you have it.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of `fail` depends on the monad. In the `Maybe` monad, `fail` returns `Nothing`.

```
instance Monad Maybe where
  return = Just

  (Just x) >>= k = k x
  Nothing  >>= _ = Nothing

  fail _ = Nothing
```

However, in many other monads `fail` translates to `error`, since that is the default implementation. The monads which provide their own `fail` are usually the ones in the `MonadPlus` class, where you can have `fail` return `mzero`, which is `Nothing` in the `Maybe` monad.

In practice, I don't recommend using `fail` since it's so unclear what it will do. Instead, use the appropriate failure mechanism of the monad you're in, whether that's `mzero`, `throwError` or something else.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because of the fail call. Look at how Maybe is an instance of the Monad typeclass:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-Maybe.html#Maybe

```
fail _              = Nothing
```

Comment: n.b. you can find this by [hoogling Maybe](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Maybe) and following the correct hyperlink to the docs, and then clicking the "source" link on that page, usually in the upper-right hand corner.